# How to find the non-repeating string from the list of string

Tags: java, python, c++, string, algorithm

There is given a list of strings out which we have to print the unique strings. Unique string is a string which is not repeated in the list of string.

```
Ex li = [ram,raj,ram,dev,dev]
unique string = raj.
```

I thought of one algorithm.

First sort the String array, then check the adjacent string if its equal then move forward otherwise its a unique string.
But here the time Complexity is very high for sorting the string array.

Can any body help me in finding the more efficient algorithm then mine algo?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make a frequency counter (which could be just a hashmap) to count the number of occurrences of each string (linear time). Then print out only those strings that have singleton counts (linear time)

Comment: thanks @inspectorG4dget. I got it.

Comment: Start by picking a language.

Comment: @shmosel I use java for coding. I tagged python and c++ also in the question because I wanted to known the efficient algorithm not code. If I get the efficient algorithm I can code in any language. As well as this question will also be posted in python and c++ community and I can get the best solution from diverse coders. And  major competitive programmers do coding in c++.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below

```
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("ram", "raj", "ram", "dev", "dev");
    Map<String, Long> nameCount = names.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()));
    List<String> unique = nameCount.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L).map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(nameCount);
    System.out.println(unique);
```

ouput

```
{dev=2, raj=1, ram=2}
[raj]
```

**EDIT**

```
    List<String> uniq = new ArrayList<>();
    names.stream().sorted().forEach(n -> {
        if (uniq.contains(n)) {
            uniq.remove(n);
        } else {
            uniq.add(n);
        }
    });
```

Instead of list map cab be used to check contains in O(1)

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

You can solve your problem in O(n) complexity.

just create a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store the word counters, and than access just the words with `count == 1`

### Solution 2

This solution is not Liniar time, but stil been a good one.

You can create a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) with a count property, so will be easy to find the nodes with `count == 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this simple python implementation, which is based on the concept of using a **HashMap**:

```
li = ['ram','raj','ram','dev','dev']
hash = dict()
for item in li:
    if item in hash:
        hash[item] += 1
    else:
        hash[item] = 1

print "unique string(s):",

for key, value in hash.iteritems():
    if value == 1:
        print key,
```